# Chromakey -video-editing in Unix?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, software-rec, video, video-editing

My friends are recommending me to use OSx for video-editing but trying to use old good OSs such as Debian and Ubuntu. How can I do chromakey -video-editing in some Unix or Linux?

Comment: I asked for recommendations [here](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/5406/how-should-i-do-chromakey-video-editing) about platform so keep this question simple, just on Unix.

Comment: kdenlive does the trick in Ubuntu. However, it is not as fancy as we wish.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo have you tried OpenShot? How does it compare to KDEnlive?

Comment: kdenlive is more like a non-linear editing system meanwhile openshot is more for simple video editing, aiming to be (someday) a full powered NLES. I have tested openshot since Ubuntu 9.04 and in my experiences and professional needs (I make video for a TV station), openshot won't fit the requirements for a fully powered NLES. Of course, if it is about the birthday video or any other videos you can go for openshot, it is yet good for that and supports lots of codecs and formats, etc. But if you make serious video (I make some news and special coverage editions), you should consider kdenlive.

Comment: BTW: kdenlive is having better support. I once dropped a comment and a mail in the forums and blog for support in openshot and I am yet waiting for an answer. I can say openshot has improved, yes. But they yet have lots of things to work in. Specially in the support area. Have a look at the VLMC, which was in the same condition as openshot when I tested both in 11.04, who knows? I am sure they are better now. Good luck!

Comment: Other BTW: We're yet expecting the open source release for Editshare's Lightworks who has already dropped their "free" version for Windows. They also complained about the "how hard is" to make an open source for Linux but they didn't say they won't do it. Anyway, I have tried the free version for windows and I couldn't make it work so far. http://www.lwks.com/

Answer (score 1):

*I am gathering here candidates, writing in progress.*

It is much easier to use Chromekey with OpenShot than with Blender. KDEnlive looks more pro but also harder to use. There are rumors about free versions of softwares such as Editshare's Lightworks.

**Alternatives**

> - OpenShot [here](http://www.openshotvideo.com/): video editing software
> - Blender [here](http://www.blender.org/): 3D modelling
> - KDEnlive [here](http://www.kdenlive.org/): video -editor, suggested by Geppettvs D'Constanzo
> - VLMC [here](http://trac.videolan.org/vlmc/), suggested by Geppettvs D'Constanzo

**Hints**

> - **Blender** use Node Editor and there select somehow some Chromakey -effect -- more [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Materials/Nodes/Editor).

Comment: Do you have any evidence that VLMC does chromakey.

Comment: @EvanCarroll no just listed Geppetvs's suggestion. If it does not, feel free to edit.